# How to manually group Radio Buttons Rails 4

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, grouping

I have 2 radio button in line for each table row. I need for them to work in a way that only 1 button in each row can be clicked. Here's code where only one per column can only be selected due to rails automatically grouping them if they have same name attribute

```
        ...<tbody>
        <% users_in_group(params[:group_id], params[:event]).each do |user| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user.fname + " "+user.lname %></td>
                <td>fill</td>
                <td>fill</td>
                <td><%= radio_button_tag 'project[absent_user_ids][]', user.id, false %></td>
                <td><%= radio_button_tag 'project[tardy_user_ids][]', user.id, false %></td>
            </tr>
        <%end%>
        </tbody>...
```

Problem here is that I DO NOT want to change name parameter due to me having to re-implement the controller all over again... I will take answers if you can help me make check boxes behave in similar way.

Comment: Radio buttons are designed to only allow you to select one. Use checkboxes and javascript to only allow one to be checked (and double check in your controller, too).

Comment: Yes, that's why RB's will suit my needs better. I just don't know how to override Rails way of grouping them by name attribute.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. Rails isn't grouping the radio buttons, the rules of HTML are. You can only have one selected with the same name. If you can't have different names you can't use radio buttons.

Comment: Yeah I have realized that. Trying to use js to do the check boxes but my js skills are pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fighting and advice from ptd here is the solution for some people to reference. Here are the form tags:

```
...<tbody>
    <% users_in_group(params[:group_id], params[:event]).each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= user.fname + " "+user.lname %></td>
            <td>fill</td>
            <td>fill</td>
            <td><%= radio_button_tag 'project[absent_user_ids][]', user.id, false %></td>
            <td><%= radio_button_tag 'project[tardy_user_ids][]', user.id, false %></td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
    </tbody>...
```

Note I have left them the same. The way I am grouping them here is by value hence for absent and tardy the value (user.id) will be the same but different for each iteration.

Here is jQuery I have dug up and modified to do the selection.

```
 $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
       var group = "input:checkbox[value='" + $box.attr("value") + "']";
       $(group).prop("checked", false);
       $box.prop("checked", true);
    } 
    else {
       $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
 });
```

Basically this gives functionality of a radio button per se but allows you to un-check the boxes. I fetch and group the boxes by value attribute instead of name which allows mw to submit the input to controller under absent and tardy param array.

Feel free to correct me. This works but it may not be as pretty and shiny as it could be.